# How to create Prince PDF without page breaks?

Tags: princexml

Is it possible to direct Prince XML to convert from HTML and create an output file with no page breaks at all, a PDF file that is just one continuous page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually specify a very tall paper size, like this:

```
@page 
{
    size: 210mm 1485mm
}
```